# What is a counterexample for this one?

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, continued-fractions

Let $x$ be an irrational number.

Let $\{a_0\}$ be the sequence of positive integers except for $a_0$ such that $x=a_0+K(1/a_n)$.

Let $a,b$ be integers such that $b>0$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $|x-a/b|<1/b^2$.

Is there a counterexample of such $a,b,n$ such that $a/b\neq a_0 + K_{i=1}^n (1/a_i)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Comment: What is $K$ and what is $K_{i=1}^n$?

Comment: @5xum $K$ is just an infinite continued fraction and $K_{i=1}^n$ is the n-th convergent

Comment: But that means that $K(1/a_n) = 1/a_n$, is it not?

Comment: @5xum No.. Indeed, K(1/a_n)=K_{n=1}^\infty (1/a_n)$. Isn't this the standard notation? This notation is used in wikipedia for "generalized continued fraction" page.

Comment: @5xum A better notation would have been $K_{n=1}^\infty (a_n)$, I think. But you can think of the analogous situation where one writes $\sum a_n$ without the limits. In informal settings, it's okay.

Comment: Just take $K_{i=1}^n (1/a_n)$ as $[0;a_1,...,a_n]$ and $K(1/a_n)$ as $[0;a_1,...]$

Comment: It's known that if $|x-(a/b)|<(1/2)b^{-2}$ then $a/b$ is a convergent to the continued fraction of $x$. But if $(1/2)b^{-2}<|x-(a/b)|<b^{-2}$, there's no reason to think $a/b$ is a convergent. See whether $x=\sqrt2$, $a/b=24/17$ works.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look into my comment?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I have tried it. Thank you. Would you write that counterexample as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(17\sqrt2-24)(17\sqrt2+24)=17^2\times2-24^2=289\times2-576=2$$ so $$0<\sqrt2-{24\over17}={2\over17(17\sqrt2+24)}\dot={1\over\sqrt217^2}$$ where $a\dot=b$ means $a$ is very close to $b$; in particular, $0<\sqrt2-{24\over17}<{1\over17^2}$. But the convergents to the continued fraction for $\sqrt2$ are $1/1,3/2,7/5,17/12,41/29,\dots$ so $24/17$ is not a convergent.